# Visual Studio 2010 sort xml/xaml attributes

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xaml, plugins, alphabetical-sort

In Visual Studio 2010 is there an option or does anyone know of a plugin that will allow you to sort your xml/xaml attributes alphabetically?

I would like to be able to hit a hotkey and have this:

```
<Button
    Grid.Row="1"
    IsEnabled="True"
    IsDefault="True"
    ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource InsertButtonContentTemplate}"
    Click="_insertButton_Click"
    Content="Insert"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Grid.Column="1" />
```

alphabetize its attributes and turn into this:

```
<Button
    Click="_insertButton_Click"
    Content="Insert"
    ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource InsertButtonContentTemplate}"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    IsEnabled="True"
    IsDefault="True"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: I have never found one, I use an Npp plugin to sort my attributes.  It works fine, but it's not integrated in VS2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this Visual Studio 2010 plugin](http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/) during my travels. It seems to do pretty much what I was looking for. (The plugin can be found at http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Here's the link to the VS Gallery version: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3de2a3c6-def5-42c4-924d-cc13a29ff5b7

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XAML Markup Attribute Sorter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51f575f9-96d1-41f5-8fc3-62f1633080bf) - sorts the attributes of any well formed XML such as XAML and XML files.